# E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) 22.04 when installing ROS 2 Humble

Tags: 22.04, dpkg, ros

I have just upgraded Ubuntu from 18.04 to 20.04 and then 22.04, now I am trying to install ROS2 Humble Desktop and then I get the following error. I am not very familiar with linux in general so I am not really sure what to do. I have tried a couple of online solutions but nothing works and i keep getting the error. Some guidance would be appreciated.

```
Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree... Done
    Reading state information... Done
    ros-humble-desktop is already the newest version (0.10.0-1jammy.20231207.082253).
    0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
    8 not fully installed or removed.
    After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
    Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
    Setting up libhdf5-openmpi-dev (1.10.7+repack-4ubuntu2) ...
    update-alternatives: error: /var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/mpi corrupt: slave link same as main link /usr/bin/mpicc
    
    
dpkg: error processing package libhdf5-openmpi-dev (--configure):
        installed libhdf5-openmpi-dev package post-installation script subprocess retur
        ned error exit status 2
        dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libhdf5-mpi-dev:
        libhdf5-mpi-dev depends on libhdf5-openmpi-dev; however:
        Package libhdf5-openmpi-dev is not configured yet.

   
dpkg: error processing package libhdf5-mpi-dev (--configure):
       dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
       dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libvtk9-dev:
       libvtk9-dev depends on libhdf5-mpi-dev; however:
       Package libhdf5-mpi-dev is not configured yet.
    
dpkg: error processing package libvtk9-dev (--configure):
          dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libflann-dev:amd64:
          libflann-dev:amd64 depends on libhdf5-mpi-dev; however:
          Package libhdf5-mpi-dev is not configured yet.
    
dpkg: error processing package libflann-dev:amd64 (--configure):
     dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libvtk9-qt-dev:amd64:
     libvtk9-qt-dev:amd64 depends on libvNo apport report written because the error 
    message indicates it's a follow-up error from a previous failure.
No apport report written because the error message indicates it's a follow-up error from a prev
    ious failure.
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
tk9-dev (= 9.1.0+really9.1.0+dfsg2-3build1); however:
      Package libvtk9-dev is not configured yet.
    
dpkg: error processing package libvtk9-qt-dev:amd64 (--configure):
     dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libpcl-dev:
     libpcl-dev depends on libflann-dev; however:
      Package libflann-dev:amd64 is not configured yet.
     libpcl-dev depends on libvtk9-dev; however:
      Package libvtk9-dev is not configured yet.
     libpcl-dev depends on libvtk9-qt-dev; however:
      Package libvtk9-qt-dev:amd64 is not configured yet.
    
dpkg: error processing package libpcl-dev (--configure):
      dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
      dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ros-humble-pcl-conversions:
      ros-humble-pcl-conversions depends on libpcl-dev; however:
      Package libpcl-dev is not configured yet.
    
dpkg: error processing package ros-humble-pcl-conversions (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigurNo apport report written because MaxRep
orts has already been reached ed
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ros-humble-desktop:
      ros-humble-desktop depends on ros-humble-pcl-conversions; however:
      Package ros-humble-pcl-conversions is not configured yet.
    
dpkg: error processing package ros-humble-desktop (--configure):
     dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
    Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.26-1ubuntu3) ...
    Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
    Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu3) ...
    Processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:amd64 (2.72.4-0ubuntu2.2) ...
    Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.35-0ubuntu3.6) ...
    Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
    Processing triggers for libreoffice-common (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.4) ...
    Processing triggers for mailcap (3.70+nmu1ubuntu1) ...
    Errors were encountered while processing:
     libhdf5-openmpi-dev
     libhdf5-mpi-dev
     libvtk9-dev
     libflann-dev:amd64
     libvtk9-qt-dev:amd64
     libpcl-dev
     ros-humble-pcl-conversions
     ros-humble-desktop
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: What are the lines immediately before? "libhdf5-openmpi-dev package post-installation" is the important part. Everything that followed was a cascading error. In the postinst script, I see that it tries to do update-alternatives, and we need to know which command fails, so we need to see the lines before your output.

Comment: I closed the initial terminal i used to try to install ROS but i re-ran the command and I've updated the question with what I get before the errors i included. Thanks.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/62464086/10477326 work?